# pandas version of SQL CROSS APPLY

Tags: python, sql, pandas, t-sql, dataframe

Say we have a DataFrame `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Id": [1, 2],
    "Value": [2, 5]
})

df
    Id  Value
0   1   2
1   2   5
```

and some function `f` which takes an element of `df` and returns a DataFrame.

```
def f(value):
    return pd.DataFrame({"A": range(10, 10 + value), "B": range(20, 20 + value)})

f(2)
    A   B
0   10  20
1   11  21
```

We want to apply `f` to each element in `df["Value"]`, and join the result to `df`, like so:

```
    Id  Value   A   B
0   1   2       10  20
1   1   2       11  21
2   2   5       10  20
2   2   5       11  21
2   2   5       12  22
2   2   5       13  23
2   2   5       14  24
```

In T-SQL, with a table `df` and table-valued function `f`, we would do this with a CROSS APPLY:

```
SELECT * FROM df
CROSS APPLY f(df.Value)
```

How can we do this in `pandas`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could apply the function to each element in `Value` in a list comprehension and use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to concatenate all resulting dataframes. Also assign the corresponding `Id` so that it can be later on used to [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) both dataframes:

```
l = pd.concat([f(row.Value).assign(Id=row.Id) for _, row in df.iterrows()])
df.merge(l, on='Id')

   Id   Value  A   B
0   1      2  10  20
1   1      2  11  21
2   2      5  10  20
3   2      5  11  21
4   2      5  12  22
5   2      5  13  23
6   2      5  14  24
```

Comment: Solid answer. I use this method a bit with similar files from different time periods to aggregate the data into a large data structure.

Comment: Thanks -- I was going to use an approach like this but I thought there might be a pandas method for it. Didn't know about `assign` -- handy.

Comment: You're welcome @Denziloe! Don't forget you can accept if it solved it for you :)

Answer (score 2):

One of the few cases I would use [`DataFrame.iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html). We can iterate over each row, concat the cartesian product out of your function with the original dataframe and at the same time `fillna` with [`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html) and [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html):

---

```
df = pd.concat([pd.concat([f(r['Value']), pd.DataFrame(r).T], axis=1).bfill().ffill() for _, r in df.iterrows()], 
               ignore_index=True)
```

---

Which yields:

```
print(df)
    A   B   Id  Value
0  10  20  1.0    2.0
1  11  21  1.0    2.0
2  10  20  2.0    5.0
3  11  21  2.0    5.0
4  12  22  2.0    5.0
5  13  23  2.0    5.0
6  14  24  2.0    5.0
```